# IF AND statement excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a large list with names in my source data from which i've filtered out the duplicates creating an unique name list. Now I want to check these names against a different column with causes in the source data. What I'm trying to do is:

"Check range (client) in source data for a certain *name*, if TRUE then check the second range (cause) for a certain *cause* then display the amount of times these both come back as TRUE"

[image: example of data]

I added an image to show you what I'm trying to do. The grey data is the filtered data with the causes horizontally displayed. The blue data is the source data. In cell C2 in this picture im trying to get it to display "2" (amount of times 'name' is 'Mr. Aa' AND 'cause' is 'technical').

So far i've come up with the following (Range E2:E9 is named "client", F2:F9 is named "cause"):

```
=IF(AND(name="Mr. Aa",cause="Technical");1;0)
```

But that doesn't work because the AND-function checks the entire range of 'client' and 'cause' and if any of the values come back as UNTRUE then the whole check comes back as UNTRUE.

Im feeling like I'm also missing a COUNTIF somewhere... I've been fiddling with this for a while and i'm feeling this should not be so complicated but I'm just not seeing it. Hope you can help.

Comment: Have you tried using a Pivot Table to do this kind of data analysis?

Comment: This... basicly did the same thing and was a lot quicker :) Never worked a lot with pivot tables. I'll have to see what is more useful for the end purpose. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in cell B2
=countifs($E$2:$E$9,$A2,$F$2:$F$9,B$1)
You can copy the formula into the other cells in columns B, C and D and it should work

Comment: Countifs solved my problem (and will solve many problems). Guess I was barking up the wrong tree with my formula. Thanks for the tip!